# What is the encoding this string?

Tags: python, utf-8, server

I want to convert this string

```
á¼¸ÏƒÏ€Î±Î½á½·Î±Ï‚ Î’Î±Î¹Ï„Î¹Îºá¿†Ï‚ Î¸á½³ÏƒÎ¹Ï
```

to Greek in python:

```
Ἰσπανίας Βαιτικῆς θέσις
```

The problem is that I have json data, which I read into a dataframe with column names including greek text such as the above.

When I read it from a cloud server, it is read in the correct format:

```
Ἰσπανίας Βαιτικῆς θέσις
```

But when I read in jupyter lab from a local computer it is read like this:

```
á¼¸ÏƒÏ€Î±Î½á½·Î±Ï‚ Î’Î±Î¹Ï„Î¹Îºá¿†Ï‚ Î¸á½³ÏƒÎ¹Ï. I
```

I tried to use

```
def utf8(x):
    return x.encode(encoding="utf-8")
```

but this only gives me this result:

```
b'\xe1\xbc\xb8\xcf\x83\xcf\x80\xce\xb1\xce\xbd\xe1\xbd\xb7\xce\xb1\xcf\x82 \xce\x92\xce\xb1\xce\xb9\xcf\x84\xce\xb9\xce\xba\xe1\xbf\x86\xcf\x82 \xce\xb8\xe1\xbd\xb3\xcf\x83\xce\xb9\xcf\x82'
```

which doesn't seem helpful.

Both data in the server and the local computer seems the same, but I do not know why it shows the result in different format. Is there a way to convert my string to the proper format?

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is a UTF-8 to <strike>latin1</strike> [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
>>> s = 'Ἰσπανίας Βαιτικῆς θέσις'

>>> print(s)
Ἰσπανίας Βαιτικῆς θέσις

>>> print(s.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252'))
á¼¸ÏƒÏ€Î±Î½á½·Î±Ï‚ Î’Î±Î¹Ï„Î¹Îºá¿†Ï‚ Î¸á½³ÏƒÎ¹Ï‚
```

This suggests that while your file is properly encoded as UTF8, when you are loading it into jupyterlab it gets decoded using the system CP-1252 encoding.

The better solution is to find the setting where this choice of encoding happens and change that to the proper UTF-8 encoding. Odds are you are either [opening](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file yourself where you can pass the encoding, or you're using a higher-level reader which again should take an encoding.

But if somehow that's not possible you can even reverse the mojibake manually (as a workaround):

```
>>> broken = 'á¼¸ÏƒÏ€Î±Î½á½·Î±Ï‚ Î’Î±Î¹Ï„Î¹Îºá¿†Ï‚ Î¸á½³ÏƒÎ¹Ï‚'

>>> print(broken)
á¼¸ÏƒÏ€Î±Î½á½·Î±Ï‚ Î’Î±Î¹Ï„Î¹Îºá¿†Ï‚ Î¸á½³ÏƒÎ¹Ï‚

>>> print(broken.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8'))
Ἰσπανίας Βαιτικῆς θέσις
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for the responses, the second reply works for only a specific text, then I recognized that I should change the system encoding from utf 16 (default win 10) to utf 8 .

it is very easy:

go to the 
--->Administrative language setting.

In the "Language for non-Unicode programs"
section, you can see the currently set
language. To change it, first, click on

---> Change system locale. then check the box

"Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"[image]

after restarting then it is done!

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. But as I've said in a comment: if you're loading the data to jupyterlab with code (rather than some sort of GUI or whatever) then we can help you do that in a way that doesn't rely on a proper system locale.

Comment: @Andras Deak     can you give me another solution, how can I handle Unicode issues ,  I have this dictionary

Comment: gfrac={"":0,"ιβ":1/12,"ς":1/6,"δ":1/4,"γ":1/3,"γιβ":5/12,"L":1/2,"Lιβ":7/12,"γο":2/3,"Lδ":3/4,"Lγ":5/6,"Lγιβ":11/12,"η":1/8,"Lς":2/3,"ςL":2/3}
gint={"":0,"α":1,"β":2,"γ":3,"δ":4,"ε":5,"ς":6,"ζ":7,"η":8,"θ":9,"ι":10,"κ":20,"λ":30,"μ":40}

Answer (score 0):

finally, another solution would be to open the file in Jupiter notebook by encoding utf 8

```
Omega = pd.read_json('../data/OmegaStructure2.json',encoding="utf8")
Xi = pd.read_json('../data/XiStructure2.json',encoding="utf8")
```